# Allowing app to download data during Power Nap

Tags: cocoa, osx-mountain-lion

I would like to use Power Nap as a developer to download data for my app. The automatic wake-up feature is a nice thing. Could this be possible with a Mac App?

I know what Apple allows; it is written everywhere.

But can I, say, update data in my app (that is, not Documents in the Cloud, Mail, Reminders, etc.), maybe big data, like new maps?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with Xcode ore mountain lion.

Comment: Similarly, I would love to have Power Nap upload stuff to Backblaze

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope - there are no public APIs relating to Power Nap available for use by third-party developers. Sorry!